# Universal relative HTML path in Linux, OS X, Windows

Tags: html

I should send HTML code of email message to another person.
Before doing this I tried to test if the code renders properly in different browsers, on different operating systems.

On Linux found out that images stop showing.
Obviously it's connected with relative path to the images.
On Mac I have this and it works:

```
<img src="/Users/username/Documents/project/images/button.png" style="display: block;" width="283px" border="0" /></a>
```

So I tried to replace this part

```
/Users/username/Documents
```

with

```
/
```

or

```
~/
```

to refer to root or home directories respectively in order to point to proper files that would be accessible under any user.
But neither of these methods works.

Is there a way to specify relative path so that HTML page shows correctly even if I hand over the code to somebody?

Comment: All the paths you've supplied are absolute paths. Relative paths should just work.

Comment: @Quentin oh yeah, thanks. If I change path to `/project/images/button.png ` or `~/project/images/button.png` it'll be relative path, right? But this also doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: No. If you start with a `/` then it is an absolute path. If you start with a `~` then you're depending on operating specific handling of file paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure, you don't begin your path with a `/`. This means that the path is absolute. Just start your path with the folder name. You can also use `..` to access the parent folder, or it's subfolders, if you don't know how they're called. For example:

`../images/button.jpg` to access a picture in a folder structure like that:

```
-Documents
|–—Projects
  |—code
  | |–myhtml.html
  |—images
    |–button.jpg
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I'm a little ashamed because of how simple the solution was.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably going to be easier to just host the image somewhere, like [tinypic](http://tinypic.com/), and generate a URL which you can then put in the src attribute instead of linking it to a local file, which is likely to not work as the recipient of your e-mail probably doesn't already have that file in the exact right directory.

Comment: sorry, maybe I haven't made it clear: I need to pass the code and the images to another developer for check. So the email isn't for end users. But the image hosting is great advice, I've been thinking about this from the beginning.

Comment: So the image won't be embedded in an e-mail, you're just sending them the code you've created for a website?

Comment: It will be embedded but for now I'm just sending the code for that future e-mail to check before distribution. It's actually a task for me as an intern.